# How to inherit fields properly without making them open to the package?

Tags: java, oop

Say, I have a package `Pack` containing classes `A` and `B`. `A` is self-contained and no one (even in the `Pack`) should see `A`'s insides, so most of the fields and methods are `private`.

Now I want to extend `A` to change one of its `private` methods keeping the rest - let it be class `AMod`. Doing it requires most of `A`'s fields and the method to override to be `protected`, but `protected` gives access to the package.

So how do I create `AMod` inside `Pack` so that `AMod` has an access to `A`'s fields and methods while no one else does? Make a nested/separate package?

<s>UPD:</s>

<s>UPD2:</s>

UPD3:

As Jacob G. suggested, my code needed redesigning, and I managed to remove the derived class from the architecture. Thanks for help!

Comment: Besides making it package-private, there's not much else you can do.  It's bad design to make something private that you want to modify from a different class.

Comment: @JacobG.: making an abstract `ABase` for two classes feels unnecessary though. The example in the question might be bad design, but I do not see an appropriate way to fix it

Comment: "The example in the question might be bad design, but I do not see an appropriate way to fix it" - The appropriate way to fix it would be to redesign it entirely.  There's no reason why a private method should be overridden from another class.

Comment: Why not use a single class with method overloading?

Comment: @JacobG.: looks like the question is more about OOP than Java. See the UPD: I have two similar builders for two similar object types and want to avoid code duplication

Comment: Alex, post code examples.

Comment: @JacobG.: see UPD2

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one answer I find missing: don't be so focused on using **inheritance** in order to avoid code duplication.

If you only need a subtle variation of behavior of `A` then you should *first* consider to "wrap" around `A` (for example via [decorator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm)) instead of `extending` A - the good old [FCoI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)!

If that isn't possible: have a very close look at the *common* behavior of `A` and `Amod` and extract those parts in a *common* base class.

Finally: don't get **too** energetic about java access modifiers in the first place. In the end, they **help** you to communicate a certain thought or idea. "Evil-willing" people will always find a way to work around your intentions. What I am saying is: if you are concerned that your team members use your class in the wrong way ... that is a **social** problem; and you will **never** be able to solve that on the technical layer. You have to solve it on the social layer, too (by *educating* people to ensure that they **understand** what to do; instead of hoping that `private` here or `protected` there will prevent them from doing the wrong thing).

In other words: establish a simple policy such as "only what is marked `public` is meant to be `public`; anything else is not" might be able to table such discussions for all times. Versus spending hours and hours to find a perfect private-protected solution within source code.

Comment: Yet you can prevent the social problem by providing access levels properly ;) At least partly. I think a correct design may save lots of time to the person who will use the product, be it a class, a library, or a complete program. Variations of "Only `public` is public" are good rules of thumb for certain cases, but they do not save you from mistakes, as you'll have to keep a track of the modifiers all the time. Anyway, thanks for the tips, I think they might be helpful in the future

Comment: Sure. My main point is: if somebody is unhappy, he could go in and change things himself. You can't really prevent that. So it is somehow about balancing efforts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting code.

My advice would be to first move `B#stepBMod` into `A.java`.  Then, you can pass a `boolean` parameter to `A#build`; with this, you can rewrite `A#build`:

```
public Result build(boolean mod) {
    stepA();

    if (mod) {
        stepBMod();
    } else {
        stepB();
    }

    stepC();

    return result;
}
```

Now, `B.java` isn't needed anymore.

Comment: The problem is `A` and `AMod` are used for different purposes and should not be merged

Comment: Why would they not be merged if they have the exact same fields/methods other than one method?  If you don't want them to be merged, then just use two different classes.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is two parts. `1)Accessing fields` and `2)Accessing methods`.

Case`1)`, you should make class `A`'s fields `protected`. This means no one can access it by name, except `derived classes`.

Case`2)`, you cannot access a `protected` method by name, unless in a `derived class`. But still you can access a `protected` method by name using an object of `A`. In order to prevent other classes making objects, your `A` class should be abstract.

Here is an example

```
public abstract class A{
    protected int n;
    protected void display(){
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public void demo(){
        B object = new B();  
        object.display();   
    }
    public void modify(){
        n = 0;
    }
}
```

Update

```
class A
{
public A(Args args){...}
public Result build() {
    stepA();
    stepB();
    stepC();
    return result;
}
protected void stepA() {...}
private void stepB() {...}
protected void stepC() {...}
protected T field;
}

class AMod extends A
{
public AMod(Args args){
super(args);
...
}
public Result build() {
    stepA();
    stepBMod();
    stepC();
    return result;
}
private void stepBMod() {...}
}
```

Comment: "This means no one can access it by name, except `derived classes`." - no, the package has access to `protected` fields

Comment: @Alex You do not understand `protected` modifier clearly. This is way you asked a question about it. I'm giving you the correct info. If you do not believe in my answer. try it yourself. use these codes and see the result.   `public abstract class A{
 protected int n;
}`   `public class B{
 public void modify(){
  System.out.println(n);
 }
 
}`   derive class`B` and see the difference

Comment: See class `Alpha` fields visibility to class `Beta` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: @Alex I understand that you are confused by the documentation explanation. I used to do so. until I ask my professor and got the same answer that i'm giving to you. try the code in my previous comment.

Comment: Well, the code above works, and that's the problem. `protected` gives access not only to the derived classes, *but also to the whole package it's in*. I wanted a way to give access *to the derived classes only*

Comment: @Alex Are you sure that you tried the code above without extends statement? If you did you should get this error message `B.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.println(n); 
                     ^
  symbol:   variable n
  location: class B
1 error`

Comment: Oh, I thought you mistyped the code and corrected it so that it compiled. The correction was to replace `n` with `new A(){}.n` - again I gained access from the package

Comment: By using `{}` you are making an object of anonymous class. you are not using the definition of class `A`. and if you try to make object of class `A`, you will get error because it is abstract class